# faulty cipher caesar java program

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I wrote a program in java for caesar cipher, where the program takes in text file as input stored in my computer and encrypt it based on the key value provided by the user. Then this encrypted file must be saved back on computer in text file format. I have been trying to locate where i went wrong but i guess i need a little help from someone more experienced in java. So heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class trial
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        String textFile="plaintext.txt";
        String cipheredFile=" ciphertext.txt";
        String line= null;
        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(textFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter(cipheredFile,true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);


        int swvalue;
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select 1: Encrypt, 2: Decrypt, 3: Get Frequency");
        int msg= input.nextInt();
        swvalue= Integer.valueOf(msg);

        switch(swvalue)


        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Encrypting the file");
            System.out.println(" Please enter a value for key");
            int keyvalue= input.nextInt();

            String[]  filearray=null;
            while(( line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            { 

            char[] toEncrypt=line.toCharArray();

                for(int i=0;i<toEncrypt.length;i++)
                {

                int charPosition= indexOf(line.charAt(i));
                int finalValue=(keyValue+charPosition)%26;
                char replaceValue=line.charAt(finalValue);
                line+=replaceValue;



                }


             bufferedWriter.write(line);
             bufferedWriter.newLine();

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            break;


        case 2:


            System.out.println("Decrypt the file");
            break;



        case 3:

            System.out.println(" Get frequency");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I'd start with sorting the code. Remove unnecessary lines, unused or duplicate variables, etc. . That should clarify quite a lot. And that implementation isn't the caesar cipher, but just pseudorandomly swapping characters around

Answer (score 0):

This is where the rotation should be:

> ```
> int charPosition= indexOf(line.charAt(i));
> int finalValue=(keyValue+charPosition)%26;
> ```

*But this not rotation!*

Instead of shifting *the position* in the string, you should shift ***the value***:

```
int value = line.charAt(i);
int finalValue=(keyValue+value)%26;
```